# Open Windows Snipps to Desktop

Tags: windows, screenshot, notification-area, snipping, snipping-tool

I take screenshots using Windows Snipping Tool.  The flow is frustrating:

1. Win+Shift+S to open the tool.
2. Take the screenshot.
3. Snipping tool closes and Windows generates an alert.
4. Open the Notification Area find the screenshot.
5. Click the screenshot to reopen the snipping tool with the actual screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOi8F.png)

I would prefer to have the snip open on the desktop (skip steps 3-5).  I have been unable to find a setting that opens directly to the desktop.

Let me know if there is a way to get screenshots to open directly to the desktop.

Comment: No such setting that I can see and none in Power Toys either. I have Snipping tool set to open when I have got my screenshot. Skips the notification step.  Windows 11 Snip tool

Comment: I typically just open Snipping Tool, take and save my screenshot, then close the snipping tool.

Answer (score 0):

This was also such a hassle for me so I did the following:

**At Desktop:**

- Right click
- Add shortcut
- Enter path:

> search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20ScreenClip&crumb=fileextension%3A~<.png%20OR%20System.Generic.String%3A.png&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CSam%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CPackages%5CMicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy%5CTempState%5CScreenClip

It should provide a shortcut folder to screenshots you've made using windows snipping tool

**Explanation:**

Essentially the path on top shows only the png files in the temp file where Windows store that screenshot.

I got it by opening windows explorer, typing the path seen below in the address bar and typed ".png" in the search bar.

The resulting url address should be similar if not the same to the block above then I just made it to a shortcut function in my desktop

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip

**NOTE: The images are still in Temp file so it will be deleted when you reset your device**

Hope this applies to your machine and that it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am using this workaround.   I hope to eventually find a way to skip the extra clicks.